# HTML Fixed Width Table, columns won't resize

Tags: html, html-table, cell, tablelayout, fixed-width

I have a div with a fixed width of 400px.  There's a table inside the div that is larger than 400px, so I want the div to scroll.  That works fine.  but I can't change the width of the cells.  I need cell 2 to be 200px wide.

```html
<div style='width:400px;overflow:scroll'>
<table style='border:1px solid black'>
<th>field1</th>
<th style='width:200px'>field2</th>
<th>field3</th>
<th>field4</th>
<th>field5</th>
<th>field6</th>
<th>field7</th>
<th>field8</th>
<th>field9</th>
<th>field10</th>
<th>field11</th>
<th>field12</th>
<th>field13</th>
<th>field14</th>
<th>field15</th>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the text in your cells that prevent them from sizing smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display: block`. If you want table-cells to have widths, add `table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;` from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670402). Unfortunately, that doesn't work with your scroll functionality.

```html
<div style='width:400px;overflow:scroll'>
<table style='border:1px solid black'>
<th>field1</th>
<th style='width:200px; display: block;'>field2</th>
<th>field3</th>
<th>field4</th>
<th>field5</th>
<th>field6</th>
<th>field7</th>
<th>field8</th>
<th>field9</th>
<th>field10</th>
<th>field11</th>
<th>field12</th>
<th>field13</th>
<th>field14</th>
<th>field15</th>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `nowrap` attribute to your `<th>` element. More info about[`nowrap`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_nowrap.asp) Attribute

```html
<div style="width: 400px; overflow: scroll">
    <table style="border: 1px solid black">
        <th>field1</th>
        <th style="width: 200px" nowrap>field2</th>
        <th>field3</th>
        <th>field4</th>
        <th>field5</th>
        <th>field6</th>
        <th>field7</th>
        <th>field8</th>
        <th>field9</th>
        <th>field10</th>
        <th>field11</th>
        <th>field12</th>
        <th>field13</th>
        <th>field14</th>
        <th>field15</th>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks.  Although I prefer the answer below using display:block, but this is good too.