# Why is CSS width on a TD overridden by viewport width?

Tags: html, css

When a width value is applied to table cell, once the table width reaches the viewport width, the rule then becomes ignored, e.g.

```
td, th { width: 400px; }
```

I would expect a 10-column table to be (around) 4000px, but Firefox and Chrome only stretch out the table to the viewport width ([see Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abogvgsb/4/)).  Upon which, the cell width isn't actually set to 400px.  I read in the question below that `table-layout:fixed` is used to force cell widths, but it doesn't work here.

Two similar questions exist [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670402/why-is-my-html-table-not-respecting-my-css-column-width) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767459/why-td-width-is-not-working-or-not-followed), but they only address initial widths, and don't discuss the viewport limitation.

Why does this happen please?  I see there is a workaround...

```
td, th { min-width: 400px; max-width:400px; }
```

...but it just seems odd when `width` alone should achieve exactly that purpose.

Comment: you only need `min-width` for your workaround fyi.

Comment: @gaynorvader Good call, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display:table-cell ( which is the default for `td` element ) makes the `td` have widths restricted to the `table` width. if the table has 100px width, they will stay in 100px width. but if you set them a width of 400px and table has 100px width, they will ignore the width of table and expand without restriction. see first answer

1. add `width:0` to `table` and it will work because the table-cells can't collapse relative to a `width:0` so they expand without restriction

see snippet below or [jsFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abogvgsb/10/)

```css
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
width:0;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0.25em;
  text-align: left;
  width: 400px; // If uncommented, rule is ignored
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

2. you can set the width of the div that wraps the table and set overflow auto to it ( thats a fix not a neat solution )

see snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abogvgsb/8/)

```css
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
}
div {
 width:4000px;
 overflow:auto;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0.25em;
  text-align: left;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

3. i know you didn't set the jQuery tag in your question , but you might want to use it so you calculate the `width` of the `div` dynamically depending on the sum of the `td` widths

see snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abogvgsb/9/)

```js
var tdWidthTotal = 0;

$('td').each(function(index) {
    tdWidthTotal += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
});
$("div").width(tdWidthTotal)
```

```css
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
}
div {
 overflow:auto;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0.25em;
  text-align: left;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The *fix* I put in the question is good enough to be honest.  I'm more interested in *why* this even happens?  Its just plain confusing to me...

Comment: because that's how display:table-cell work. they get their widths relative to the table width , but you can also use `width:0` on table and it will work :) see my no 1 answer

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `display: table-cell` ignores width. You can add an element with `display: block` and `width: 400px` inside your th elements and it will work:

```
th div{
  width: 400px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abogvgsb/11/

Comment: *Apparently display: table-cell ignores width.* It doesn't appear to ignore it until the table width reaches the viewport's width, which is confusing...!  While the fixes work fine, I keen to understand *why* this happens - is there a rationale for it?